# Visual Studio Service Reference, and Auto-Generated Proxy Classes - Why should they not be passed around your classes/projects?

Tags: c#, wcf

My development approach has always been to take the data from a Visual Studio service reference's auto-generated proxy class (in a WCF project) and use that to hydrate my own custom business object.  It is then the business object that will get passed around from class to class, project to project within a large solution, rather than the auto-generated classes created by Visual Studio.

I was challenged: why bother?  Why not just pass the auto-generated class, if all we're doing is a dumb data translation?  You know I got caught out giving a 24 carat, argument winning answer.

Any help?  Why not just pass around those proxy classes and save time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Its a layer of abstraction.  You don't want to tie your business logic directly to your services.  What if you decide to not use WCF what if the service side changes.  Its the same reason you do it for DTO.
2. You may want to write custom proxies
3. You want to be able to test your business object without needing your WCF wrappers to be available
4. Auto mapper makes this almost painless.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look into the concept of an anti corruption layer from Domain Driven Design

> An Anti-Corruption Layer (ACL) is another DDD pattern that encourages
>   you to create gatekeepers that work to prevent non-domain concepts
>   from leaking into your model. They keep the model clean.
>
> At their heart, repositories are actually a type of ACL. They keep SQL
>   or object-relational mapping (ORM) constructs outside of your model.
>        ACLs are a great technique for introducing what Michael Feathers calls, in his book  Working Effectively With Legacy Code, a seam.
>
> A seam is an area where you can start to cleave off some legacy code
>   and begin to introduce changes.Finding seams, along with isolating
>   your core domain, can be extremely valuable when using DDD techniques
>   to refactor and tighten the highest value parts of your code.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419654.aspx